# Are all block and stream ciphers symmetric?

Tags: public-key, block-cipher, symmetric, stream-cipher

I'm trying to categorize my knowledge. Can I place block ciphers and stream ciphers under *symmetric* with RSA/DH under *asymmetric*?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is almost correct and in general these two classes of algorithms are distinct.

However, Simon Shepherd published a paper called **Public Key Stream Ciphers** in the *IEE Colloquium on Security & Cryptography Applications to Radio Systems, London, 3 June 1994*.

It proposes to essentially use the RSA setup and initial random seed $x_0$ from $\mathbb{Z}_{pq}$ and Blum Blum Shub type of squaring

$$
x_{k+1}:=x_k^2~~in~~\mathbb{Z}_{pq}
$$
with the keystream being $z_k=LSB(x_k).$ This can be used to (presumably transmit to the holder of the private key $(p,q,d)$ first the initial value $x_k$ encrypted with RSA, and then) the keystream
$$
a_k\oplus x_k,\quad k\geq 1.
$$
Of course BBS pseudorandom sequence generation is older than this.

Comment: It might be a good idea to point out that *in general* public-key cryptography and stream ciphers are not usually considered to be the same class of algorithm...

Answer (score 2):

> Can I place block ciphers and stream ciphers under symmetric with RSA/DH under asymmetric?

This sounds like you are trying to categorize RSA/DH as block/stream ciphers, which is not accurate.

It is possible to model RSA encryption as a block cipher, but that's an uncommon notion. "Public-key encryption" and "block cipher" indicate different concepts, even if the public-key encryption operation in question happens to be a permutation of blocks it would still create confusion to talk of it as a "block cipher".

Diffie-Hellman is  key agreement algorithm rather than an encryption algorithm, and as such is not any kind of cipher.

A better way to rephrase your statement might be:

> Can I place block ciphers and stream ciphers under symmetric cryptography, with RSA/DH under asymmetric cryptography?

To which the answer would be "yes".

> Are all block and stream ciphers symmetric?

Conventionally, yes. It is conceivably possible to define an asymmetric operation to combine the key stream. But this would be abnormal.

Comment: Symmetry is defined as having the same keys during both the (encryption and decryption) operation, correct? Then how can you use an asymmetric primitive to combine the key stream?

Comment: @MaartenBodewes A stream cipher will typically have the same operation for encryption and decryption, so you could use an asymmetric primitive in an _encryption_ mode to perform both encryption _and_ decryption as a (weird, non-standard) stream cipher. Consider encrypting a counter and using the ciphertext as keystream.

Comment: @MaartenBodewes You could use the key and nonce supplied to $\operatorname{encrypt}$/$\operatorname{decrypt}$ to generate an encryption and decryption exponent. It's a pedantic technicality, I don't advocate anyone do this, I was only noting that you could theoretically define such a monstrosity; It's not "impossible" for such a thing to exist, and I didn't want claim that it was only to have someone else provide such a counter-example. Actually see, kodlu's answer for an actual example of a "[public-key stream cipher](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/66785/29554)"